# Creating Cloudfront signed urls with time window

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, grails, amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS SDK with Grails 2.2.5. According to the AWS's well detailed documentation the sdk provides a class called `CloudFrontUrlSigner`to create signed urls, which works as expected, except it doesn't apply time restrictions - the created urls seem alive forever.

```
    String createRadioSignedUrls(String distributionDomain, String awsKey, Date from, Date until)  throws InvalidKeySpecException, IOException {

    log.debug "CREATING SIGNED URL FOR KEY (${awsKey}) ..."

    String keyPairId = "${grailsApplication.getConfig().cloudfront.keypair.id}"
    File privateKeyFile = getCloudfrontPrivateKey()

    String signedUrl = CloudFrontUrlSigner.getSignedURLWithCustomPolicy(
            SignerUtils.Protocol.https, distributionDomain, privateKeyFile,
            awsKey, keyPairId, until,
            from, null)
}
```

In my BuildConfig.groovy :

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.grails.plugins:aws-sdk:1.11.11"
}
```

Running out of ideas, I've tried out different versions, but none of the dateFrom / dateTo restrictions are applied. Could I miss some configurations somewhere? Does it depend on config of the Cloudfront domain? Any help are welcomed, thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't be possible to craft a signed URL incorrectly and have it work at all, much less have it unexpectedly never expire.  My suspicion is that the CloudFront distribution does not have [Restrict Viewer Access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesRestrictViewerAccess) enabled on the relevant Cache Behavior, so the signed URL may not actually be doing anything (and its validity may be going unchecked) -- because the object is actually publicly accessible.  Verify that?

Comment: If that isn't it, then it would be very helpful, if possible, if you could post one of the signed URLs, unaltered.